# Latency Time in Load Testing

Tags: load, load-testing, latency, performance-testing

I m Using pylot 1.26 tool for load testing but it just gives me Avg. Response Time & 
Avg. Throughput . from these parameter how can I calculate latency time??

OR suggest me some **FREE** ****TOOL**** for **load testing** which will gives me these parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our [Load Tester](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/) product captures *time to first byte* (TTFB). This is the time from the beginning of the request until the first byte of the response is received.  On small requests (i.e. GETs) that the webserver can respond to instantly (i.e. static file-based resources), this is a good indication of round-trip time. Not exactly the same as latency, but close.

I'm not aware of any load testing tools that measure latency specifically. Most just give response time and the better tools also measure TTFB.

If you have very simple tests to run, [Load Tester LITE](http://www.webperformance.com/load-testing/free-load-tester-lite.html) is free with unlimited VUs.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/).
There is dedicated listener [Latencies Over Time](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LatenciesOverTime/) which you can take from [JMeter Plugins site](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) to use together with default jmeter installation.